# Access DB unresponsive when executing VBA module

Tags: vba, ms-access, module

I have an Access database that was using a standard macro to input information from a .csv file. I wanted more error handling and more input scrubbing ability so I converted to vba code. everything was going fine in my testing db but when I brought the code over to the converted macro code, once it was executed it would freeze the db but only the main form area. the toolbars were all still active. it is like the draw function for the db is hung up. now I know the main forms code will stop while the vba code is executing but as far as I can tell the vba is getting to the end of its function and hitting the End Function. there are no loops. I've commented out all the error handling and GoTo statements and it still persists. even after commenting out all my additions and just having the original converted macro code it still persists. any ideas why it would be getting hung up? code below. even after closing the vba editor. it doesn't restore it.

```
Option Compare Database  
Option Explicit  


Function Import_Arm_CSV()  
On Error GoTo Import_Arm_CSV_Err  
   ' Dim StringVar As String  
   ' Dim Initialinput As Variant  
   ' Dim FileName As String  
   ' Dim FilePath As String  
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False  
    DoCmd.Echo False, ""  
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "EMPTY_FIELDS", acViewNormal, acEdit  
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "EMPTY_CSV", acViewNormal, acEdit  
'TryAgain:  
    'Err.Clear  
    'Asks user for Filepath  
    'Initialinput = InputBox("Please enter file path", "Import", "")  
    'Ends Function if no input or cancel is detected  
   ' If Initialinput = "" Or Initialinput = False Then Exit Function  
    'Scrubs outer quotes if present  
   ' MsgBox (Initialinput & "Before")  
    'StringVar = Replace(Initialinput, Chr(34), "", 1, 2)  
    'On bad input sent to error handler  
    'On Error GoTo InputErrHandler  
    'informs about bad input and asks to try again or not  
'InputErrHandler:  
    'If MsgBox(Err.Description, vbRetryCancel, "Bad Input") = vbCancel Then   Exit Function  
    'Resume TryAgain  

    'MsgBox (StringVar & "After")  
   'Exit Function  
    DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, "11", "FIELDS_3", InputBox("Please enter file path", "Import", ""), True, ""  
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "APPEND_TO_CSV", acViewNormal, acEdit  
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "APPEND_TO_CSV2", acViewNormal, acEdit  
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "UPDATE_FLAG", acViewNormal, acEdit  
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "UPDATE_CONV", acViewNormal, acEdit  
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "UPDATE_INDEX", acViewNormal, acEdit  
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "UPDATE_INDEX_002", acViewNormal, acEdit  
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "update_udfdate1_", acViewNormal, acEdit  
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "ARM_UPDATE", acViewNormal, acEdit  
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "UPDATE_ARMACAP", acViewNormal, acEdit  
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "UPDATE_ZIP", acViewNormal, acEdit  
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "UPDATE_TEXT_IDENTIFIERS", acViewNormal, acEdit  
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "UPDATE_TYPE_", acViewNormal, acEdit  
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "APPEND_TO_TRUST", acViewNormal, acEdit  
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "UPDATE_FALSE", acViewNormal, acEdit  
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "UPDATE_FALSE_DATE1", acViewNormal, acEdit  
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "DELETE_FALSE_DATE", acViewNormal, acEdit
    Beep  
    MsgBox "Data has been imported!", vbOKOnly, ""  


Import_Arm_CSV_Exit:  
    Exit Function  

Import_Arm_CSV_Err:  
    MsgBox Error$  
    Resume Import_Arm_CSV_Exit  

End Function
```

Comment: First thought is some kind of lock happening... Are you able to comunicate with your AccessDb in another mean? Does-it respond? In older Access version there was only one concurent user allowed...

Comment: yes if I run the module from the vba editor it reengages the db but then freezes it when its done. the top toolbars appear to create movement in the main area but the like I said up top its like the draw function isn't active so it either stays frozen but visible or becomes a white screen(tool bars and whatnot still active and visible up top).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Maybe you should read this first: [How do I ask a good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then edit your question and add some code. Nobody can say what is going wrong without seeing the code.

Comment: Thank you Wolfgang, Code added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you are setting `echo` to false and not re-enabling it.
While the Access application is frozen you can re-enable `echo` in the immediate window.
Just remember to add an `DoCmd.echo true` to the end of your `function`

Comment: Thank you YHoffman. I didn't know what the 'echo' function did. it was apart of the original macro. learned something new today!